# SQL syntax error inside CAST with case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, case, aggregate-functions

I want to list positive and negative `bank_transfers` from my DB. To do so I'm using below query:

```
SELECT
  bank_transfers.date AS day,
  CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents < 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END)) AS sum_expenses,
  CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents > 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END)) AS sum_revenue
FROM bank_transfers
JOIN customers ON customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
WHERE customers.id = 1
AND bank_transfers.date < '2020-11-26'
AND bank_transfers.date >= '2020-08-26'
GROUP BY DAY
```

But it gives me an error `syntax error at or near ")"`. I guess it comes from the `CAST` so where should I close the parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need those casts. You're not casting into any type (unless `sum_expenses` and `sum_revenue` are your custom types).

Edit: If you want to cast to integer:

```
SELECT
  bank_transfers.date AS day,
  SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents < 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END)::integer AS sum_expenses,
  SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents > 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END)::integer AS sum_revenue
FROM bank_transfers
JOIN customers ON customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
WHERE customers.id = 1
AND bank_transfers.date < '2020-11-26'
AND bank_transfers.date >= '2020-08-26'
GROUP BY DAY
```

Or use `cast(... as integer)`.

Comment: Without `CAST` I'll receive float number e.g. `-4441.0` instead of `-4441`

Comment: @mr_muscle add `::integer` or `cast(... as integer)`. I've updated my answer

Comment: @mr_muscle no, `CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents < 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) as integer) AS sum_expenses`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a `JOIN` for this query, because the customer `id` is in the `bank_transfers` table.  I also strongly recommend `FILTER` for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT bt.date AS day,
       SUM(bt.amount_cents) FILTER (WHERE bt.amount_cents < 0) as sum_expenses,
       SUM(bt.amount_cents) FILTER (WHERE bt.amount_cents > 0) as sum_revenue
FROM bank_transfers bt
WHERE bt.customer_id = 1 AND
      bt.date >= '2020-08-26' AND
      bt.date < '2020-11-26'
GROUP BY DAY;
```